# Python - PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе

Tags: python

Почему отказывает в доступе я же делаю запрос на получение прав ад. что делать ?

```
import os
import shutil

os.startfile('cmd.exe','runas')
path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'C:/Program 
Files/Blender Foundation')
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Comment: Похоже что ваш файл уже где-то открыт или используется другой программой или пользователем

Comment: И еще можно попробовать обратный слэш в путь поставить вместо обычного